# Inconsistent Badge Listing

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

My name in the header and on a question page shows me having one silver and three bronze badges.

When I go to my badges page, I see three bronze and no silver.

So one or the other is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Yaakov legimitately earned the Beta badge (on Stack Overflow I mean).

Edit: not sure in this case; might have been an old accidental award. I don't see anything in the data. I just manually updated your count as they are heavily denormalized for performance.

Answer (score 2):

You better get cracking then and earn a silver badge.